# WP_Query tax_query on ACF post_object

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-taxonomy-queries, tax-query

I have a custom post type `Wine`, which has an [ACF Field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) that links to another custom post type `Producer` as a `post_object` relation. In my Producer, I have a custom taxonomy named `Region`.

Now, what I'm trying to do is to query all the white wines where the producer's region is x.

Here's what I've tried:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'wines',
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'type',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'white'
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'region',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'alsace'
        )
    )
);
```

The problem I'm having is the `tax_query` is executed on the `wine` and not it's `producer`. I've looked at the documentation of [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) and can't seem to find an example on how to achieve it.

Could anyone please guide me?
Thanks.

### Update 1

I've retrieved the list of IDs of the producers to add it to the `meta_query`:

```
$producers = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'producers',
        'posts_per_page' => -1
    )
);

$producersIds = wp_list_pluck($producers, 'ID');
```

After that, I've updated the `$args` by adding the meta query:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'producer',
        'value' => $producerIds,
        'compare' => 'IN'
    )
)
```

Comment: It sounds like the only taxonomy that you technically have linked is the type of wine.  The region is tied through a post object, which would be stored through the meta (ACF), usually as a simple post ID.  So, you might have to request all Producers from the "Alsace" region first.  Then, add those IDs to a meta_query, while still using the type under the tax_query.  Hopefully I followed your logic.

Comment: @socki03 Yes, that's my logic. I'll try it and come back to you! Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you're getting all producers, shouldn't you be only getting the ones from the Alsace (or equivalent) region?  You should just be able to add 'region' => 'alsace' to the producers query args.

Comment: @socki03 Yeah that's what I've figured after updating my question! I got it working now! I'll post an answer for users who has the same issues later! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update 1

As @Florian pointed out, we do not need to use the wp_list_pluck function, we could simply add the `'fields' => 'ids'` to the WP_Query to retrieve the list of ids:

```
$producers = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'fields' => 'ids',
        'post_type' => 'producers',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'region',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'alsace'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Then retrieve the wines by replacing `$producerIds` by `$producers->posts`.

### Solution

First, I had to retrieve the producers from the region:

```
$producers = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'producers',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'region',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'alsace'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Then I retrieve the list of ids with [wp_list_pluck](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck):

```
$producerIds = wp_list_pluck($producers->posts, 'ID');
```

And finally, I retrieve the wines with the ids of the producers:

```
$wines = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => 'wines',
        'posts_per_page' => 12,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'type',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'white'
            )
        ),
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'producer',
                'value' => $producerIds,
                'compare' => 'IN'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Had never heard of this wp function, wp_list_pluck... very useful.

Comment: 2 things (just for clarification), shouldn't the tax query have another array wrapped around it, similar to the meta_query? (array of arrays), OR you could simplify the tax_query by just rewriting it as a simple custom taxonomy request by using the slug of your taxonomy and assigning either a simple slug or array of slugs.

Comment: @socki03 Oops! Yes there's an array wrapping in the `tax_query`!

Comment: You don't need `wp_list_pluck` if you only need the ids (although it is of course a super nifty function). You can also use the `'fields'=>'ids'` parameter to return an array of ids (`$producers->posts`). https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Return_Fields_Parameter